# Ratchet CSS and Marionette Regions

Tags: css, marionette

Hello MarionetteJS Gurus,

I have what is probably a very simple problem, but I can't wrap my head around how to solve it. I have an application with 2 regions and 1 layout, and I'm utilizing the Ratchet CSS library for prototyping.  Functionally, the goal is simple: display a list of contacts in one view, with a header and search bar.  If the user selects a contact, remove the search bar and retain only the header.

The problem appears to be the wrapping divs that are required to swap views in and out. The Ratchet CSS needs the header bars to be directly above the content section in order to properly dock them at the top of the viewport, but Marionette's regions and layouts (at least with my configuration) are preventing this from happening. Perhaps I could better structure my views?

JSFiddle of the resulting output: http://jsfiddle.net/VB7py/3/  You'll notice that the header/search area overlaps the content area.

*menuRegion* contains a footer menu, and *mainRegion* contains a layout consisting of a header region, a search region, and a "main content" region.  Below are some snippets of my code:

**Regions**

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
headerRegion: "#header-region",
menuRegion: "#menu-region",
mainRegion: {
    selector: "#main-region",
    regionType: MainRegion
  }
});
```

**Layouts/Views**

```
List.Layout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#contacts-layout",

    regions: {
        headerRegion: "#header-region",
        searchRegion: "#secondary-header-region",
        contactsRegion: "#contacts-region"
    }
});

List.Search = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template: "#contact-list-search",
    className: "bar bar-standard bar-header-secondary"
});

List.Header = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#contact-list-header"
});
```

**Templates**

```
<!-- Application Layout -->
<script type="text/template" id="contacts-layout">
    <div id="header-region" class="bar bar-standard"></div>
    <div id="secondary-header-region">

    </div>  
    <div id="contacts-region" class="content"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="contact-list-header">
    <nav class="bar bar-standard"><h1 class="title">Contacts</h1></na>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="contact-list-search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="menu-template">
    <nav class="bar bar-tab bar-footer">

    </nav>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrapping divs inside the regions did not seem to be a problem. However, you need to set those bar specific css classes to the regions instead of it's nested elements. Like:

```
    <div id="header-region" class="bar bar-standard">
        <div>
            <nav>
                 <h1 class="title">All Contacts</h1>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary-header-region" class="bar bar-header-secondary">
        <div>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/7Wd6W/

You could pre-set those classes on your region elements or add these specific classes on region initialization, see: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#instantiate-your-own-region